# Centos7 firewall not running

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7

This is what I got from status firewalld:

```
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2015-07-14 02:58:35 UTC; 35s ago
Process: 19546 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
$FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 19546 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Jul 14 02:58:35 li1201-198.members.linode.com firewalld[19546]: 2015-07-14 02:58:**35 ERROR: Exception DBusException: 
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Connection ":1.314" is not allowed to own the service "org.fedoraproject.FirewallD1" due to security policies in the configuration file**
Jul 14 02:58:35 li1201-198.members.linode.com systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

More recently, [Bug 1575845](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1575845) in Red Hat's Bugzilla tracker shows a problem in RHEL/CentOS 7.3 or later that triggers this issue. Something with dbus policy not being passed correctly. The permanent fix (for now) could be upgrading your base image to a newer version of RHEL/CentOS.

However, these commands should also work, per [this comment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1575845#c8) in the Bugzilla:

```
sudo systemctl restart dbus
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Comment: I tried this, it is saying that it is active (running), but there are some warnings and errors are displayed: ```WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
ERROR: Failed to read file "/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'
WARNING: Failed to get and parse nf_conntrack_helper setting
WARNING: ebtables not usable, disabling ethernet bridge firewall.```

Comment: These two steps worked for me in getting the firewallD restarted, but it does show a warning when checking the status: `WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a futu...ing it now.` Reading the full log from `journalctl`: `WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.
`

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on my CentOS 7 VPS (minimal install) when I installed the firewalld.noarch package as a non-root user with sudo privileges.

To fix, I had to log in as root and then erase and reinstall firewalld.

Comment: Just run into this issue myself. Additional to reinstalling the firewall I had to reboot the VPS in order to get rid of the issue.